# Number of subsets and N-dimensional cube

Tags: combinatorics

Amazing fact. The number of subsets of a set of N elements is equal to the number of vertices of an N-dimensional cube. Why?

[3 elements and 3-dimensional cube](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Lzff.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Perhaps even more amazing is that for positive integers $k$ and $n$ such that $k \leq n,$ the number of $k$-dimensional cubes that bound an $n$-dimensional cube is the coefficient of $x^k$ in the expansion of $(x+2)^n.$ (Your question is the case when $k=0.)$ See [this 29 August 2006 sci.math post](https://groups.google.com/g/sci.math/c/W_WDXmUxNGU/m/ZaL7VJc9hfgJ) for a proof. Incidentally, one way to add more context to your question as requested by @José Carlos Santos is to explain how you discovered this fact, since the image you link to only shows there are 8 subsets to a 3-element set.

Comment: Oops, "for positive integers $k$ and $n$" should be "for non-negative integers $k$ and $n$".

Comment: I was looking for a visual proof of the formula for number of all the subsets of power set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Hint

$$\begin{array}{|c|c|}
\hline
n & \text{Coordinates of } n\text{-dimensional cube} \\
\hline
2 & (0,0), (0,1), (1,0), (1,1)\\
\hline
3 & (0,0,0), (0,1,0), (0,0,1), (0,1,1), (1,0, 0), (1,1,0), (1,0,1), (1,1,1)\\
\hline
4 & (0,0,0,0), (0,0,1,0), (0,0,0,1), (0,0,1,1), (0,1,0, 0), (0,1,1,0), (0,1,0,1), (0,1,1,1), (1,0,0,0), (1,0,1,0), (1,0,0,1), (1,0,1,1), (1,1,0, 0), (1,1,1,0), (1,1,0,1), (1,1,1,1)\\
\hline
\end{array}$$

Can you relate the coordinates to permutations of sets?

Comment: Thank you for your reply, Carefree Xplorer.